# how can I show the console of a headless running vbox vm

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-console

I have a virtualbox headless VM running on CentOS 7. I can show the console of the VM by opening up the virtualbox manager, right clicking the machine, and choose "Show". Is there a way to do this (pop up the console of the headless guest) without opening up the gui manager, i.e., from the command line? I've tried most likely commands for vboxmanage but get errors or the wrong result. I also asked on Unix & Linux without success. On superuser there are responses to similar questions, but they all relate to connecting to the guest via ssh or rdp. I want to get the functionality provided by the gui "show" tab via the command line.

Comment: Please be more descriptive when you say "get errors or the wrong result". What are the errors or what are the wrong results. Also it'd be helpful if you list the commands you already tried.

Comment: Wrong result: the console does not pop up. Errors: vboxmanage startvm archive -- The machine 'archive' is already locked by a session (or being locked or unlocked). vbboxmanage debugvm show - console does not pop up. etc.